# Creating a dynamic chart in Excel VBA using macro and .End function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a dynamic chart based on the last row and column. The problem occurs when I have to define the Chart range. It identifies both the last row and column but when I try to set the chart range the last column is equal to the full spreadsheet.

**Code:**

```
Sub Spiderweb_test()
'
'Spiderweb_test Macro
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject

    lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set chtRng = Range("A4:lc" & lr)
    Set ChartArea = Range("a" & lr + 3 & ":f" & lr + 15)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(317, xlRadarMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=chtRng

    Set chtObj = ActiveChart.Parent
    chtObj.Top = ChartArea.Top
    chtObj.Left = ChartArea.Left
    chtObj.Height = ChartArea.Height
    chtObj.Width = ChartArea.Width
End Sub
```

**Picture of output:**

[image: Picture of output]

Comment: `lc` is the number for the column, thus `Set chtRng = Range("A4:lc" & lr)` is something like `.Range("A4:55")` - You should use `.Cells` when using numbers for columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Set chtRng = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(lr, lc))
```

Since lc is actually the number of the column, not the letter.
Hence the Chart Range is not being set correctly.